# how do I Sort and organize data from csv file in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach

I have a csv file with my vehicle inventory, I would like to know how to sort that inventory by how long I have had it.

This is what I would like to output -

30 cars 0-30 days old

25 cars 31-60 days old

10 cars 60-90 days old

2 cars 90+ days old

I have a variable called $numberDays which calculates the days I have had the car and gives me an integer like "30" or whatever it is..

Here is what I have - 
$csv is the array

```
foreach($csv as $car){

//Calculate days in stock
$todaydate = date("m/d/Y");
$dis = $car[21]; //date stocked in
$startTimeStamp = strtotime($todaydate);
$endTimeStamp = strtotime($dis);
$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);
$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400; 
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);

}
```

Comment: Yes $csv is an Array sorry ill update the question

Comment: Okay, can you give a little example of your csv? Just 3 lines are enough for testing my code :)

Comment: Sorry not sure what your asking for, do you want to see the csv file structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$howlong = array("0-30days"=>0, "31-60days"=>0, "61-90days"=>0, "91+days"=>0);
foreach($csv as $car){
  ...
  $numberDays = intval($numberDays); //last line in your code
  if($numberDays<=30) $howlong["0-30days"]++;
  elseif($numberDays<=60) $howlong["31-60days"]++;
  elseif($numberDays<=90) $howlong["61-90days"]++;
  elseif($numberDays>90) $howlong["91+days"]++;
}

echo $howlong["0-30days"]." cars 0-30 days old";
echo $howlong["31-60days"]." cars 31-60 days old";
//etc
```

Comment: +1 for giving a simple solution; I would define the counters as array and push the objects into them, to make further use of this "sorting" easier.

Answer (score 0):

Something like should work for you. It is untested!

It should work if $csv[n][21] is a string that contains a date.

```
// Simple Bubble-Sort
// Sorting by Date ASC
$changed = true;
while ($changed) {
    $changed = false;


    for ($n = 0; $n < count($csv) - 1; $n++) {
        if (strtotime($csv[n][21]) > strtotime($csv[n + 1][21])) {
            // Swap!
            $tmp = $csv[n];
            $csv[n + 1] = $csv[n];
            $csv[n] = $tmp;

            $changed = true;
            // We could add a "break" here
        }
    }

}
```

## Edit

Okay now you updated your question and my answer does no more fit your question. I'll still leave it here for other searching with the keywords.